# iOS app displays messy when adding arm64 in Valid Architectures

Tags: ios, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, arm64

I'm upgrading an old app to new version. It worked normally until Apple requires arm64 in Valid Architectures.
Before:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qhwccgdwp3dvina/Right.png?dl=0

After adding arm64, I have to pull down to see this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/25p87jijj7tt36c/Wrong2.png?dl=0

I'm using these libs:

- ETFoursquareImages
- PPNetworkCheck
- MSSlideNavigationController
- AMLocalization
- CXAlertView
- YLProgressBar
- MarqueeLabel
- SVPullToRefresh
- SDWebImage
- MagicalRecord
- ASIHTTPRequest
- MBProgressHUD

Can anyone have any clue to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

The root reason of all these is not the libs. It's my mistake when using int and float in the data source of UITableView methods:

```
-(int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Change them to NSInteger and CGFloat, and it works fine with 64bit architecture.